# Extract FAQ content from websites of different domain name

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, dialogflow-es, data-extraction

Currently, I have used Scrapy and bs4 to do web crawling on individual website's faq contents.

**However, as different websites format their html structures differently, I will need to adjust the tags or xpath whenever I crawl a new faq page.**

I have discovered that google's Dialogflow has introduced "Knowledge base" feature, in which the user just need to parse a faq website to their system and they will generate list of faq.

Now, I am thinking of ways to speed up my goal:

- ***Crawl FAQ data from different websites.***

**May I know if there's any lib I can use to speed up the process?
Or if there's a way for me to download the generated Q&A pairs from Dialogflow client.**